# Software design for Client side form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So Im using the MEAN framework to build my web app. Like all other apps it requires a login & registration.

**My Approach so far has been:**

1. Every major function of my app has its own AngularJS controller
2. I have a data filter controller, which helps to filter data within the app. But my filter controller **DOES NOT** connect to the server it self. I created a AngularJS service that handles all actions with the server.
3. And I have a **"login controller"**

The login controller is responsible for as the name suggests handling logins.

**My Question:**

My question then is that is carrying out Client Side form validation (*i.e checking the fields are not empty, the email is of correct format etc*) within a angularJS controller a good design approach?

Should I create a service that handles all the validation? Should the validation functions be private (i.e in javascript modules). Whats the best design approach for this?

**Below is my login controller code:**

```
login.controller('login', function($scope){

$scope.checkValidEmail = function(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("email");
   var err = document.getElementById("emailErrorMessage");
   var emailLabel = document.getElementById("emailLabel");
   var success = document.getElementById("emailSuccessMessage");
   var email = $scope.userEmail.toLowerCase();

   var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");

   if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= email.length) {

       success.style.display = "none";
       err.style.display = "-webkit-inline-box";
       elem.style.borderColor = "#ef4d23";
       elem.style.backgroundImage = "url(./img/error_sign.png)";
       elem.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
       elem.style.backgroundPosition = "325px";
       elem.style.backgroundSize = "16px 15px";
       emailLabel.style.display = "none";
       err.style.color = "#ef4d23";
       err.innerHTML = "Email address is incorrect!";
       $scope.valid = true;

       return false;
   } else {
       success.style.display = "-webkit-inline-box";
       success.style.color = "#27ae60";
       success.innerHTML = "Email looks great!";
       err.style.display = "none";
       elem.style.borderColor = "#27ae60";
       elem.style.backgroundImage = "url(./img/correct_sign.png)";
       elem.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
       elem.style.backgroundPosition = "325px";
       elem.style.backgroundSize = "12px 16px";
       $scope.valid = false;
   }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question then is that is carrying out Client Side form validation
>   (i.e checking the fields are not empty, the email is of correct format
>   etc) within a angularJS controller a good design approach?

Not on itself (angular uses a specific controller to do that for you), but the way you are using it is horrible:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("email");
...
success.style.display = "-webkit-inline-box";
```

AngularJS provides bindings. You are completely avoiding those and accessing your View from your Controller (bad!) and modifying your view from your controller by adding CSS rules (even worse!).

> Should I create a service that handles all the validation? Should the
>   validation functions be private (i.e in javascript modules). Whats the
>   best design approach for this?

You could do that, sure, but the best approach to do that is to use Angular the way it is supposed to be used. Take a look at the [Forms developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms):

```
<input type="email" ng-model="user.email" name="uEmail" required="" />
<br />
<div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.uEmail.$touched">
  <!-- could aldo use ngClass to add a CSS class on error -->
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.required">Tell us your email.</span>
  <span ng-show="form.uEmail.$error.email">This is not a valid email.</span>
</div>
```

You keep your validation on the View side, just like it is supposed to be, and bind your models to your controllers so they are much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I am amazed why you are using controller function to validate your form. You are using MEAN framework so you should use angular built-in directives to validate your form. It's better, fast and easy so.

**Angular Form Validation:**

```
   <form name="myForm">
     <input type="text" name="name" ng-required="true" />                   
     <p class="help-block" ng-if="myForm.name.$dirty && myForm.name.$error.required">
        <i><b>Name</b></i> is required.
     </p>
    </form>
```

Like this you can do for email, number etc.
For Full reference: [click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)